# angular: ng-model binds but ng-change doesn't fire (nor does ng-blur)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

The input value gets correctly bound to the model (and to 0 in this case, I've tried with other numbers and it alwyas gets initialized correctly), but the ng-change function never fires (I tried ng-blur instead of ng-change and it also doesn't fire...)

HTML (jade):

```
div.app_area(ng-controller="AppCtrl")
            div.app_wrapper
              label.inline Value

              span.glyphicon.glyphicon-random.convert_icon

              .input-group
                 input.form-control(type="text", ng-model='usd', ng-blur='convert_to_btc()', placeholder="USD")
                 span.input-group-addon.glyphicon.glyphicon-usd

              .input-group
                 input.form-control(type="text", ng-model='btc', ng-blur='convert_to_usd()', placeholder="BTC (Approx.)")
                 span.input-group-addon.glyphicon.glyphicon-bitcoin
```

The controller:

```
app.controller("AppCtrl", function AppCtrl($scope, $http, $interval ) { 
  $scope.usd = 0;
  $scope.btc = 0;

  some_func = function() {
    //do something
  }

  convert_to_usd = function() {
    alert("hallo");
    $scope.usd = $scope.btc * $scope.bitfinex_price;
  }

  convert_to_btc = function() {
    alert("hello");
    $scope.btc = $scope.usd / $scope.bitfinex_price;
  }
```

Comment: Are you missing the `$scope` when defining `$scope.convert_to_usd` in your controller (and likewise for your other function)? If the code is exactly as you've posted, that would be part of your problem.

Comment: @DRobinson I am...please provide your response as an answer so I can accept it :) Thank you!

Comment: As some_func was only used internally, I was lured to think I would not need the $scope. prefix for the functions needed in the view....